# Dynamical systems, conjugacy

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider a family of dynamical systems generated by equations: $y'=ax+b, \ \ a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it true that in this family:

1) There are 4 types of phase portraits up to topological conjugation?

2) $x'=at+b_1 $ and $x'=at+b_2$ are always topologically conjugate.

Here $x=\frac{at^2}{2} + b_1t+C$ and $x=\frac{at^2}{2} + b_2t+C$, $C \in \mathbb{R}$

Two dynamical systems $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \times X \rightarrow X$, $\psi: \mathbb{R} \times Y \rightarrow Y$ ( $X, Y$ - metric spaces) are topologically conjugate if there exists a homeomorphism $h: X \rightarrow Y$ such that $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, y \in X: \ \psi(t, h(y)) = h(\varphi(t,y))$.

By the way, 3) Does this mean that $h(s)=2s$ is the homeomorphism for systems generated by $y'=y$, $y'=2y$? In the first equation $y=C \cdot e^{x}$, in the second one $y=C \cdot e^{2x}$?

Comment: Are you sure you want $x$ in your equations and not $y$?

Comment: Everything can be solved explicitly here--so, which problem do you face exactly?

Comment: @Artem I'll correct that. You're absolutely right. I forgot to "synchronize" the definition with the problem :)

Comment: Did you write down the dynamical system generated by the differential equation $y'=ay+b$? Otherwise, we may run in circles for hours...

Comment: @OP: Why did you delete your previous comment (the one addressed at my first comment, to which my second comment replies)?

Comment: @ Did, I deleted it, because I realized there was a mistake there and it was too late to edit it. Is $\varphi(x,y) = \frac{ax^2}{2} + b_1x+y$ ?

Comment: In the third question ($y'=y, \ y'=2y$) the dynamical systems $\varphi(x,s) = se^x$, $\psi(x,s) = se^{2x}$ are conjugate but the homeomorphism should be $h(s)=s^2 \text{sgn} s$

Comment: If you keep $x$ in your equations, then $y'=ax+b$ is *not* a dynamical system.

Comment: Is it ok now? Is $\varphi(t,y) = \frac{at^2}{2} + b_1t+y$ the dynamical system generated by $x'=at+b_1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $b$, let $$\varphi_b:(t,x)\mapsto\varphi_b(t,x)=\tfrac12at^2+bt+x$$ denote the flow associated to the differential equation $y'(t)=at+b$. That is, for every $(t,x)$, the solution of $y'(t)=at+b$ with initial condition $y(0)=x$ is given by $$y(t)=\varphi_b(t,x).
$$
Let us assume that $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_b$ are conjugate. Thus, there exists some function $h$ such that $$\varphi_b(t,h(x))=h(\varphi_0(t,x)),$$ that is, $$\tfrac12at^2+bt+h(x)=h(\tfrac12at^2+x)\qquad(\ast)$$ for every $(t,x)$. In particular, for $t=1$ and $t=2$, $(\ast)$ yields 
$$h(x+\tfrac12a)=h(x)+\tfrac12a+b\qquad(\ast\ast)
$$
and
$$h(x+2a)=h(x)+2a+2b.$$
On the other hand, $(\ast\ast)$ iterated four times yields $$h(x+4\cdot\tfrac12a)=h(x)+4\cdot(\tfrac12a+b).$$ Comparing these two expressions for $h(x+2a)$, one sees that $b=0$. Conversely, this proves that, for $b\ne0$, $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_b$ are not conjugate.

This approach can be adapted to show that $\varphi_b$ and $\varphi_c$ are not conjugate unless $c=b$.

Turning to the differential equations $y'=ay$, one sees that, now, $$\varphi_a:(t,x)\mapsto\varphi_a(t,x)=x\mathrm e^{at}$$ for every $a$ hence, for every $x\gt0$, the function $$t\mapsto\varphi_a(t,x)^{b/a}=x^{b/a}\mathrm e^{bt}$$ solves $y'=by$ with the initial condition $y(0)=x^{b/a}$. This shows that, for every $(a,b)$, $\varphi_a$ and $\varphi_b$ are conjugate on the domain $(0,+\infty)$, a conjugation function being $$h:z\mapsto h(z)=z^{b/a}.$$
Furthermore, if $ab\gt0$, $\varphi_a$ and $\varphi_b$ are conjugate on the whole real line, a conjugation function being $$h:z\mapsto h(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}z^{b/a}&\text{if}&z\gt0,\\ 0&\text{if}&z=0,\\ -(-z)^{b/a}&\text{if}&z\lt0.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: I see. Thank you a lot for explaining that all to me.

Comment: @Did The definition is symetric, you always can take $k = h^{-1}$

Comment: @themaker Right, thanks.

Comment: @Did I have one last question. What do you mean by iterating $(*)$?

Comment: If $h(x+u)=h(x)+v$ for every $x$ then $h(x+4u)=h(x)+4v$.